# Get query string from a http response

Tags: c#, .net

If I copy and past the following URL in the browser, I get a response URL with a query string sessionid in it:

https://abc.abcdefg.com/abcd/sessionServlet

I am trying to capture that response URL and session id in my code behind in .net:

```
        string url = "https://abc.abcdefg.com/abcd/sessionServlet";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Label1.Text = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
```

the response.ResponseUri contains my original URL, but not the response URL I get back from the sessionServlet.

Could anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Response URL? Is the content you are trying to obtain apart of the response body, or is it in the headers?

Comment: So i paste that URL in the browser, and i get this url back in the browser: http://devserver/myproject/login.aspx?sessionid=1341351j1oij4o1i3o13i5ho1i3j4134o. I would like to retrieve this url so i could continue with the session id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your comment about the `http://devserver/myproject/login.aspx?sessionid=1341351j1oij4o1i3o13i5ho1i3j4134o` URL appearing the browser from vising the URL `https://abc.abcdefg.com/abcd/sessionServlet`, you're probably being redirected using HTTP 301 or 302.

If so, I'd add `request.AllowAutoRedirect = true` <sup>[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)</sup> which will allow your web request to follow that redirect. Then `response.ResponseUri.Query` should have the querystring that you're looking for.

Comment: I thought the AllowAutoRedirect is set to true by default? I added it in my code but still am not getting the URL with the session id.

Comment: @Hello_Everyone You're correct, the default is true, but wanted to ensure it was following it. If it isn't following it, then it's probably redirecting you using some other method like Javascript or a `<meta>` tag. May want to use something like Fidder or Wireshark to see what exactly is going on to get you to that page with the session ID.

Comment: Used fiddler, found out that it's redirecting me to the dev server, so it's not picking up the query string in my local. Problem solved. Thank you!